# Can't turn off ARC for JSONkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, jsonkit

Using [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) for a project that is ARC enabled, and having issues. I flagged the files appropriately as `-fno-objc-arc` and tried a build, but it is **still throwing errors like ARC is enabled**. Any ideas what I could be missing?

For clarity, I flagged the file in Build Phases->Compile Sources->JSONkit.m

EDIT: screen shot of the errors. These are the same errors I got before adding the flag for the file to be ignored by ARC
[image]

Comment: Seems like an Xcode problem there. Have you tried cleaning and building the project again?

Comment: @fbernardo Tried a clean and build, quit and reopen of xcode, delete the files and re-added (yes, I copied files and they are added to target)

Comment: @KevinBallard added a screenshot of the error

Comment: What Xcode version you using?

Comment: 4.6 (yay arbitrary comment minimum length limits)

Comment: Just a dumb comment, but why aren't you using the native JSON methods built into iOS?

Comment: @ElJay Not a dumb question :-) Need to support <5.0

Comment: Gotcha.  Have you checked out SBJSON?  I think there is an ARC compatible version of that out now (that is what I used to use before drawing the line at iOS 5 and using the native stuff.

Comment: Paste a screen shot of your build settings for `JSONKit.m`.  Also paste in the full build command for `JSONKit.o`.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12756483/77567) will help you find the full build command if you don't know where to find it.

Comment: @ElJay JSONKit also claims to be faster than the native JSON parser

Comment: I would have to see that to believe it.  I did some benchmarking with SBJSON vs native awhile back and native was much around 3X faster with processing a 7800 record JSON array from a web-service.

Comment: @ElJay http://www.bonto.ch/blog/2011/12/08/json-libraries-for-ios-comparison-updated/

Comment: @robmayoff How do I get the build settings/build command for an individual file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as you mention you have follow these steps already please set compiler flags for JSONkit.m file also -fno-objc-arc

also

if its not working then tried:-[image: these steps]

1.you can delete the App directy under ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications and ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

2.then you can start Xcode ; in the menubar you can find Project -> Clean!

Comment: This answer, combined with fully deleting the files and their references, then re-adding and flagging them, did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning up your derived data. X-Code sometimes does not clean up build warnings/errors. Open the organizer, Projects, select your project, click on delete behind the derived data. Then do a clean build.

Comment: Thought this might of been it, but no such luck